# Implement Gantt Chart in Phabricator

Tags: phabricator

Good Day,

Does Phabricator has feature or supported for creating Gantt Chart? or if there's documentation on how to implement Gantt Chart for my projects. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Phabricator (already abandoned project) dev team said they never works for clients who has needs for such charts.
Despite that some users from time to time make good tries with Phab API to get data from task and make Gantt charts.
Look here and you could make some usefull stuff
https://github.com/slashsbin/phabulous